# Why are my results different from what I want?

Tags: java

First, I will ask the user to type the password, then my code will measure the strength of this password as the following rules:

- Length:

  - From 8 to 12, 1 point.
  - > 12, 2 points.
- Contains at least one uppercase letter: 1 point
- Contains at least one lowercase letter: 1 point
- Contains at least one digit: 1 point
- Contains non-alphanumeric characters (symbols): 1 point

I have already finished the code but when I type the password is "Hellllllo@123", the result will equal 7 instead of 5. I know my mistake will happen when the password contains the digit and non_aplhanumeric characters but I don't know how to fix it.

```java
    public class passwordDemo
    {
        String password;
        int point;

        //getter and setter
        public int getPoint()
        {
            return point;
        }

        public void setPoint(int point)
        {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public String getPassword()
        {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password)
        {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public passwordDemo(String password)
        {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public passwordDemo()
        {
        }

        //main method

        public int point()
        {
            point = 0;
            //length
            if (password.length() >= 8)
            {
                point += 1;
            }
        //upper and lower
            String pass_upper = password.toUpperCase();
            String pass_lower = password.toLowerCase();

            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
                if (password.charAt(i) == pass_upper.charAt(i))
                {
                    point += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < password.length(); k++) {
                if (password.charAt(k) == pass_lower.charAt(k))
                {
                    point += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        //digit
            String digit = "0123456789";
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < digit.length(); k++) {
                    if (password.charAt(i) == digit.charAt(k))
                    {
                        point += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //non-alphabetic
            char[]non_alphabetic = {
                '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-',
                '+'};
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < non_alphabetic.length; k++) {
                    if (password.charAt(i) == non_alphabetic[k])
                    {
                        point += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return point;
        }
    }
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Strength_password
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        passwordDemo password = new passwordDemo();
        System.out.println("Type your password");
        password.setPassword(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println(password.point());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `break` when checking for the digit(s).

Comment: But when I add "break" when checking for the digit, the outcome is still equal to 7 instead of 5

Comment: Your breaks only break out of the *inner* loop. To break out of the outer loop you need to add a label to the outer loop (like `digitCheck:`) and then use the labelled break `break digitCheck`). Labelled breaks are a rarely-used feature in Java. Mostly because more often than not you can make the code better structured and more readable by extracting stuff into methods instead.

Comment: I also don't see your check for "length greater than 12" that adds another point. The code looks like you are still learning, in which case loops and breaks are good to learn, but you *could* make it much simpler (for the programmer :-) ) by [matching against a regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-) for each of your "contains" conditions. Amongst other simplifications.

Comment: maloomeister & JoachimSauer have it right: you only break once on digits check, meaning you keep looping in the wrapping for loop.
On top of that, you might need to check style, as Java classes would usually be named with first letter uppercase.
To wrap up on frIT comment, you might prefer checking against regex, as done here: https://www.javacodeexamples.com/check-password-strength-in-java-example/668

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

First the code. Explanations appear after the code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordDemo {
    String password;
    int point;

    // getter and setter
    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        if (password != null  &&  !password.isEmpty()) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null or empty password.");
        }
    }

    public PasswordDemo(String password) {
        setPassword(password);
    }

    // main method
    public int point() {
        point = 0;
        // length
        int len = password.length();
        if (len >= 8  &&  len <= 12) {
            point++;
        }
        else if (len > 12) {
            point += 2;
        }
        // uppercase
        if (password.matches("^.*[A-Z].*$")) {
            point++;
        }
        // lowercase
        if (password.matches("^.*[a-z].*$")) {
            point++;
        }
        // digit
        if (password.matches("^.*[0-9].*$")) {
            point++;
        }
        // non-alphabetic
        char[] non_alphabetic = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '+'};
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < non_alphabetic.length; k++) {
                if (password.charAt(i) == non_alphabetic[k]) {
                    point++;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return point;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type your password");
        PasswordDemo password = new PasswordDemo(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println(password.point());
    }
}
```

- I changed the class name so as to adhere to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).
- I don't think you need a no-argument constructor because member `password`, of class `PasswordDemo`, should not be null or empty since it doesn't make sense to have a null or empty password. Remember, you should always write code that handles unexpected data. Hence method `setPassword` throws an [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) if the method argument is either null or an empty string.
- Method `point`

  - Note that `point++` is the same as `point = point + 1`. Similarly, `point += 2` is the same as `point = point + 2`.
  - If the password length is between 8 and 12, then one is added to `point`. If the password length is **not** between 8 and 12 but the length is greater than 12, then 2 is added to `point`.
  - I use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to check whether the password contains at least one uppercase letter. I also use regular expressions to check whether the password contains a lowercase letter and whether it contains a digit. The regular expression for the uppercase letter check is as follows.

    1. `^` means the start of the password
    2. `.` means any character and `*` means zero or more times, so `.*` means zero or more characters.
    3. `[A-Z]` means a single, uppercase letter of the English alphabet.
    4. `$` means the end of the password.

Hence the regular expression searches for an uppercase letter in the password. I assume you can now understand the other two regular expressions. `^.*[a-z].*$` searches for a lowercase letter and `^.*[0-9].*$` searches for a digit.

Finally, the test for a non-alphanumeric character uses your code that iterates through the characters of the password and for each character, it iterates through the list of non-alphanumeric characters. As mentioned in the comments to your question, a `break` only exits the loop it is in. Since the `break` is in a nested loop, it only exits the inner loop. I use a boolean variable to test whether I need to `break` in the outer loop. This is not the only way but it is the way I prefer. Another way (as mentioned in the comments to your question) is to use a label. Note that there is no "best" way. Decide which way you prefer and use it. Just remember that, as a professional programmer, other programmers may need to make changes to your code. Hence it is important that the code is written in a way that other programmers can easily read and understand.

According to the rules (as I understand them and as I have implemented them in the above code), if the password is

```
Hellllllo@123
```

then its point value is 6.

- The length is greater than 12 so two points.
- It contains an uppercase letter so another one point.
- It contains a lowercase letter so another one point.
- It contains a digit so another one point.
- It contains a non-alphanumeric character so another one point.

The value is therefore

```
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

So unless I did not understand the rules, you are mistaken if you think that the point value of *Hellllllo@123* is 5.